Windows Server 2022 offline DNS Forwarders fails validation
I have an offline  network with two domain controllers that are DNS servers.
There is slow performance  when accessing  Active Directory and Group Policy.
In DNS Properties > Forwarders, the DCs are in the list of Forwarders. When I edit the list, it attempts to validate. After 10 seconds it shows the Server FQDN for both, but shows an error in the Validated section.

An Unknown error occurred while validating the server.

There are no failures in DNS Administrative Role  Event log. Port 53 is allowed through the firewall. I can ping each of the servers from each other.
What am I missing?
Why does it fail validation?

I  don't understand. What do you mean the domain is offline? Why do you have your DNS servers configured as forwarders? For themselves? That doesn't make sense.

@joeqwerty by offline I mean this system is not connected to the internet. DNS forwarders were put in their on there own when they were installed as Domain Controllers. I did not add them.
